# Why does the .capitalize method don't work here?

Tags: python-3.x

**Here is my code in python**
[This is the whole program in gist.](https://gist.github.com/Einsteinlau/c9135743b7e2cab809efd971a486ab1d)

```
import random
    list= [ "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" ]
    my_decision = random.choice(list)
    while True:
        game = input("Let's play Rock-Paper-Scissors Game! Please enter your decision: ")
        game.capitalize()
```

**this method don't work. When i enter rock or paper or scissors, it just failed to capitalize the first letter.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
game = game.title()
print(game)
```

If you put `"rock"` it'll print out `"Rock"`, and if you put in `"two words"`, the script above will print out `"Two Words"`.

Comment: Thanks. Nice information for me.

Answer (score 0):

The method works fine here. You just aren't assigning it's result to `game`.

```
while True:
    game = input("Let's play Rock-Paper-Scissors Game! Please enter your decision: ")
    game = game.capitalize() # You need to assign to `game`
```

But more importantly `while True` is a infinite loop. Unless there is more code that you aren't showing. If not ensure you add `break` to exit the loop when you want.

Comment: Yup. This is only part of my program. You can access the whole code in the link provided in the post above :). But, why if i don't assign it to `game`, it can't work? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think i see the answer 